# Start Animation from zero visibility to full?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using startanimation method to produce a fadein effect on an image. I want the fadein effect to work after few seconds of delay, and before that i don't want the image to be visible. I cannot use the setalpha method as the animation takes the current state of the image. So what should i do here?

```
imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgfade);

fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        imageView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation );
     }
}, 8000);
```

Comment: Make another animation that runs for 2 seconds and essentially doesn't do anything but keep the image hidden. Run it first, then this animation.

Comment: Actually i have just used setalpha twice once before the handler call in which i've set it to 0, and again inside the run method. It works fine now, thnks for your reply:)

Answer (score 0):

put `imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` after `imageView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation );`